# Keyboard input java

Tags: java, input

I am somewhat new to Java and I wanted to try receiving input from the keyboard.  I understand that I must use a Scanner, but when I do, the program will not wait for input.  Instead it will instantly throw a NoSuchElementException.  The code that I am trying to use is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int move = -1;
        String moveColumn = "";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a move: ");
        moveColumn = scan.next();
        move = Integer.parseInt(moveColumn);

        System.out.println("You chose " + moveColumn + ".");
    }
}
```

From everything that I have read, this block of code should work, but it doesn't.  Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong, or at least point to some resources that may be able to help me out?

Comment: Have you tried `scan.nextLine()`?

Comment: You can also use scan.nextInt(), so you don´t have to convert the string.

Comment: I just copied and pasted that code into Eclipse and it ran without a hitch.. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I have tried scan.next line(). I have tried scan.nextInt().  And I do not use an side I typed it using vim.

Comment: Your code works. I recommend you to install NetBeans or Eclipse and also jdk -> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code on the terminal and it performed fine. The program waits for either a number (expected value) or a string, which throws an expected "NumberFormatException". As Survivor mentioned (March 9th) it would be wise to install an IDE such as Eclipse, or Netbeans As they provide useful debugging tools.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace 
moveColumn = scan.next();
move = Integer.parseInt(moveColumn);
with
move = scan.nextInt()

Answer (score -2):

You can use 
moveColumn = scan.nextLine();